# I a trying to ping a host using ansible which does not use default ssh port but I am not successful

Tags: ansible, ping

this is my hosts file

```
ansible_host=XX.XXX.xx.x ansible_port=9301

[all:vars]
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

and my command is: `ansible all -i hosts -m ping`

and I keep getting:

> ansible_host=xx.xxx.xxx.xx | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ansible_host=xx.xxx.xxx.xx: Name or service not
>   known", 
>       "unreachable": true }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, based solely upon your posted content, that you left off the inventory hostname; all of those `key=value` pairs, such as that `ansible_host=` part, are for assigning hostvars to an *existing* inventory hostname. You'll want an inventory file like this:

```
my-awesome-host ansible_host=XX.XXX.xx.x ansible_port=9301
```

In the future, you can confirm what ansible thinks about your inventory via the `ansible-inventory` command:

```
ansible-inventory -i ./your-inventory-file.ini --list
```